# nginx with passenger

Tags: nginx, passenger

I'm trying to move from Apache + Passenger to Nginx + passenger on my Ubuntu Lucid Lynx box.

When I install passenger:

```
sudo gem install passenger
```

and

```
cd /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-2.2.14/bin
sudo ./passenger-install-nginx-module
```

everything is fine (no error). Nginx is downloaded and compiled and installed at the same time (when selecting the first option during passenger installation). By default it is installed in `/opt/nginx`.

I end up with the configuration file `/opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf`; This conf file was automatically updated with passenger config). The thing I do not understand is that I also have the configuration file `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`. What is the purpose of this one when it seems that the conf file in `/opt/...` is the main one?

When I run `/etc/init.d/nginx start`, it starts correclty saying that `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` is ok. Does it mean that it does not check the other conf file?

I updated `/etc/init.d/nginx` script and added `/opt/nginx/sbin` at the beginning of the PATH and it seems the correct conf file is taken into account. It seems like I have two nginx installations where I only relied on passenger to install it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You *did* end up with 2 Nginx installations:

1. The one installed globally by your OS's package manager (/usr/sbin/nginx). This uses /etc/nginx/nginx.conf as configuration file by default.
2. The one installed by Phusion Passenger (/opt/nginx/sbin/nginx). This uses /opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf as configuration file by default.

Only (2) has Phusion Passenger support. Ignore (1) and do not use it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but what I do not understand is how the first one has been installed ? I did not issue any apt-get install nginx command. Well, thank you, this is much clearer now :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is a programming related question, but anyway...

It seems like passenger installation have configured nginx to look for config file in /etc/nginx. Post your nginx configure flags and check if /etc/init.d/nginx overrides config file path.

http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxCommandLine

Comment: Hello, well it seems that I got 2 installations. Still do not know how this happens but this is the case. I probably missed something in my installation script :) thanks anyway. Regards,Luc